# Nikon Tethered to iPad, iPhone on import, duplicate images appear

Tags: iphone, ipad, photos, camera, import

I am using a Nikon Z7 and Z7II. Connected via the Apple camera connection kit to an iPad Mini 5 (14.7.1) and an iPhone 6s Plus (14.7.1). As I shoot, the images will appear in the "import" screen of the Photos app. However, they show up duplicated. They are not duplicated on the camera. If I disconnect the camera and reconnect, they are no longer duplicated. Only new pictures taken while the camera is connected appear duplicated. This happens in multiple apps that import images directly from a camera. This makes it difficult to work on a shoot as the screen becomes cluttered by dozens of duplicated images. Connecting and reconnecting to clear the screen is not an option during a shoot.

UPDATE:
-This happens with both JPEG and RAW.
-When I test on my Mac Mini, it works properly and only shows the single image in Image Capture. As it should.
-I am not shooting RAW and JPEG at the same time. Either one or the other.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Are you shooting both RAW and JPG?

Comment: It is happening with both RAW and JPEG.

Comment: I think @nohillside tried to ask whether you shoot RAW and JPEGs at the same time? I.e. you take one photo (shutter hit once), but your camera saves one RAW image and one JPEG.

Comment: Nope, not shooting raw and JPEG at the same time. One or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have stopped happening when I upgraded to iPad os15.